# List of List in scala

Tags: list, scala, reduce

I would like to know how can I create a List of List in the result of a reduce operation.

I've for example this lines

```
1,2,3,4
0,7,8,9
1,5,6,7
0,6,5,7
```

And I would like to get something like this

```
1, [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
0, [[7,8,9],[6,5,7]]
```

Thsi is my code

```
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(",")
    val label = Integer.parseInt(parts(0))
    (label, List(Integer.parseInt(parts(1)), Integer.parseInt(parts(2)), Integer.parseInt(parts(3)))
}
```

With this I get

```
1, [2,3,4]
0, [7,8,9]
1, [5,6,7]
0, [6,5,7]
```

But if I use a `reduceByKey` operation with a `List.concat(_,_)` I get one single List with all items concated.

```
parsedData.reduceByKey(List.concat(_,_))
```

I want a List of List, reduced by the Key.

Is there some other operation that i don't know?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: From where, does the `reduceByKey` method come from? Have you defined it yourself?

Comment: No, It is the reduceByKey that scala provides, I haven't defined

Comment: does this work ? `parsedData.groupBy(_._1)`

Comment: @Rahul No

`scala> parsedData.groupBy(_._1)
res36: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[(Int, List[Int])])] = ShuffledRDD[42] at groupBy at <console>:38

scala> parsedData.foreach(println)
(0,List(6, 5, 7))
(1,List(2, 3, 4))
(0,List(7, 8, 9))
(1,List(5, 6, 7))`

Comment: You could look at `aggregateByKey`, because your result is of type `List[List[Int]]` while `reduceByKey` expects `List[Int]`.

Comment: I see, this should work then: `parsedData.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
val data = "1,2,3,4\n0,7,8,9\n1,5,6,7\n0,6,5,7".split("\n")

val parsedData = data.map{ line =>
  val parts = line.split(",")
  val label = Integer.parseInt(parts(0))
  (label, List(Integer.parseInt(parts(1)), Integer.parseInt(parts(2)), Integer.parseInt(parts(3))))
}.toList
//parsedData: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((1,List(2, 3, 4)), (0,List(7, 8, 9)), (1,List(5, 6, 7)), (0,List(6, 5, 7)))

parsedData.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// Map(1 -> List(List(2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7)), 0 -> List(List(7, 8, 9), List(6, 5, 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is concat you are looking for.

Can you try with that:

```
parsedData.reduceByKey(_ :: _ :: Nil)
```

Which should literally create a new list with your elements inside

Comment: It doesn't work scala> parsedData.reduceByKey(_ :: _ :: Nil)
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Integer]
 required: Integer
              parsedData.reduceByKey(_ :: _ :: Nil)